# unnecessary gap on left side of button on hover

Tags: html, css, hover

i have created a button with following html and css

```css
.btn:hover, .btn--white {
    color: #fff;
}
.btn--white {
    border-color: #fff;
}
.btn {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #ed1c24;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 15px 30px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: #ed1c24;
    border: 1px solid #ed1c24;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 0;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a {
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-text-decoration-skip: objects;
}
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
a:-webkit-any-link {
    color: -webkit-link;
    cursor: auto;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.text--center {
    text-align: center;
}
.text--white {
    color: #fff;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Open sans', sans-serif;
    color: #333;
}
html {
    line-height: 1.15;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
.btn--white:before, .btn--white:after, .btn--white span:before, 
.btn--white span:after {
    background-color: #fff;
}
.btn:before, .btn:after, .btn span:before, .btn span:after {
    content: '';
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 0;
    width: 25.25%;
    background-color: #ed1c24;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms;
    transition: all 500ms;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.btn:before {
    left: 0;
}
.btn--white:before, .btn--white:after, .btn--white span:before, 
.btn--white span:after {
    background-color: #fff;
}
.btn:before, .btn:after, .btn span:before, .btn span:after {
    content: '';
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 0;
    width: 25.25%;
    background-color: #ed1c24;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms;
    transition: all 500ms;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.btn:after {
    left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="why-us" class="parallax overlay page-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="text--center text--white">
      <div class="on-scroll-reveal animated bounceInUp" data-animation="bounceInUp" data-offset="80%" style="opacity: 1;">
        <span class="heading heading--center">Why Us ?</span>
      </div>
      <div class="on-scroll-reveal animated bounceInUp" data-animation="bounceInUp" data-offset="80%" style="opacity: 1;">
        <div class="paragraph text--center">
          <p>We Represent internationally and Domestic reputed products from the printing industry</p>
          <p>Employees who have undergone intensive hands on training in Europe and overseas</p>
          <p>More Then 20 year of experience in the printing and packaging industry</p>
          <p>Technical support from professionally qualified and Experience Team</p>
          <p>Prompt and reliable service to our customers around the clock</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="on-scroll-reveal animated bounceInUp" data-animation="bounceInUp" data-offset="100%" style="opacity: 1;">
        <a href="" class="btn btn--white">
          <span>Contact Us</span>
        </a><!--btn-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

now whenever i hover over button there is this weird gap between left border and .btn:before 
[button on hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nf1Fz.png)

when inspecting the button from dev tools when i uncheck/modify these properties and hover over button the gap doesn't show up:-

- text-transform (uncheck)
- border: 1px solid #fff ===> border:4px solid #fff
- display:inline-block ===> display:block (i dont want it to be block
  'cause its full width then )
- overflow (uncheck)
- text-align: center (uncheck) (Inherited from
  div.text--center.text--white) (button goes all the way to left
  obviously)

Please tell my why this is happening and what is the right way to fix it ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue on Chrome, can you share a run-able snippet or a codepen? https://codepen.io/andrasadam93/pen/LzBLoY as a start

Comment: Please post a codepen here?

Comment: i tried creating codepen problem is not showing up in codepen and also it is not showing up in firefox even on phone it is fine.